# RSpec: Stub private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I try to test a class with RSpec2, that has some private methods, which are called from some public methods. I test the public methods with

```
@foo.should_receive(:start_training).exactly(2).times
```

if they are called and how often. My problem is, that this approach doesn't work with private methods. So, is there any way to use sth like `@foo.send(:private_method)` in combination with `should_receive`? Or any other syntax?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`should_receive(:method)` works whether the visibility of `:method` is public or private.

Comment: eehmm... I'm sure that it works. Can you explain it more what you mean?

Comment: I tried it out, when I try to call should_receive with a private method, I get `private method `start_training' called for #<Run:0x007f7f7e2ebe68>`

Comment: Could you post a bit more code?  In the spec I'm working on atm, I'm should_receive'ing private methods with no issues...

Comment: Silly me, I called the private method from another step of the test. So you were right, `should_receive` works in both cases, public AND private methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

You can use `allow_any_instance_of` method to stub or mock any instance of a class
for e.g. you have a `class` named `Foo` with some `private` methods than you can do something like this

```
allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:private_method) do
  #do something
end
```

In case if there you have `module` also, you can do something like this

```
allow_any_instance_of(Module::Foo).to receive(:private_method) do
  #do something
end
```

You can find more details about `allow_any_instance_of()` method at [Official Documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance#use-%60allow-any-instance-of%60-to-stub-a-method)

Comment: using `allow_any_instance_of` is considered a bad practise, see https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.6.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/AnyInstance

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to test the private methods?  They're private for a reason; to prevent access from external calls.  Testing the public methods that rely on the private methods should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it worth it testing private methods. Otherwise, if you have 10 public methods that rely on that one private method, you could end up repeating yourself testing the behavior of all public those methods.

Comment: @AndréHerculano yes, but you should be testing behaviour, not implementation. You would test the returns of those public methods, regardless of what private methods they use.

Comment: They didn't say they wanted to test private methods. But the test relied on some private methods that he wanted to stub out.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is: you can not stub private method.

The good one is: you can make your method `protected` and then stub it the usual way;

```
allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to(
  receive(:my_protected_method_name).and_return("foo_bar")
)
```

Comment: as pointed out in the answer above, you can stub private methods, and it has nothing to do with protected methods. Furthermore stubbing with `allow_any_instance_of` is considered a code smell and should be avoided (also recommended by Rubocop https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.6.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/AnyInstance)

Comment: Why is it considered a smell @23tux?

Comment: @SebastianPalma it's not. it's his opinion and the one of some rubocop fanatics. rubocop also say it's bad if your model in rails is > 250 lines (by default). some huge ass god models are easy 1000 and they are still slim. don't take rubocop for granted.